build the gcc5.4 in riscv, but rising the error that unknown mode 'TF'
I need to use gcc5.4 in riscv cpu.So I have replace the following files, which from this website.
./isl-0.14/config.sub
./mpfr-2.4.2/config.sub
./config.sub
./mpc-0.8.1/config.sub
./libjava/classpath/config.sub
./libjava/libltdl/config.sub
./gmp-4.3.2/config.sub

And I also have add the riscv config riscv which is from gcc10.1, copying these files into the gcc5.4 location.
(gcc)/gcc/confg/riscv
(gcc)/gcc/common/confg/riscv

But now still work wrong because of "unknown mode 'TF'". I couldn't understand what meanings it is, and how could I solve it?
The following is error info.
    ../.././gcc/config/riscv/riscv.md:330: unknown mode `TF'
    ../.././gcc/config/riscv/riscv.md:330: following context is `])'
    ../.././gcc/config/riscv/riscv.md:330: unknown mode `TF'
    ../.././gcc/config/riscv/riscv.md:330: following context is `])'
    make[3]: *** [Makefile:2226: s-preds-h] Error 1
    make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[3]: *** [Makefile:2172: s-conditions] Error 1
    ../.././gcc/config/riscv/riscv.md:330: unknown mode `TF'
    ../.././gcc/config/riscv/riscv.md:330: following context is `])'

I have read the whole code about TF, and search it in gnu.org. I still have not idea to solve it.
